# Visitors cannot reach my local Apache server

Tags: apache-httpd, connection-sharing, dynamic-dns

I have a machine running the client of noip to provide dynamic DNS. This machine is in a network where I put its ip on the DMZ because I want visitors acessing its services.

I am succesfull on access it inside my network both by the local address network and by the external IP of the network  and by the name I have registered on no-ip.

Though people outside my network are finding impossible to connect to my machine.  I could confirm the access impossibility because if I try to access the address through a web proxy, the output is libcurl couldn't connect, timeout.

Until the last week I had a colleague of mine that was accessing the service normally. But since then nothing was done and the service it is unavailable for him.

Comment: Has your noip registration expired?  You need to re-validate free accounts every three months or so.

Comment: I always renew. I got to access successfully through no-ip inside of the local network.
The problem lies outside of my LAN.

Comment: Have you verified that your router's port forwarding rules are still in place and *enabled*?

Comment: Is it not enough to setup the DMZ address. I believe that the router will forward the requests for that machine when doesn't there be a rule to port forwarding. Anyway I explicitily put the port forwarding now.
The external IP address is http://189.34.22.91.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know the ISPs blocked port 80 for customer machines. Appearently it was the problem. Monday I will know for sure if, in fact, it was only that.